# Is this a complex sentence with a dependent clause, or a simple sentence with an introductory clause?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns, complex-sentences

so I came across this sentence:
Before the invention of the printing press, books were very expensive.

I know that “books were very expensive” is the independent clause, but what about “before the invention of the printing press”? Is that a dependent clause? The way I understand clauses is that they need verbs, but that expression has no verb. So is this a simple sentence or a complex sentence? Thanks!

Comment: Introductory prepositional phrase you got there. Before long, books were cheap to print. With movable type, type could be moved.

Comment: so is it simple or complex? I take it you are saying it is simple then?

Comment: _Before the invention of the printing press_ can be considered a nominalization of _before the printing press was invented_, which is clearly a subordinate clause. This is why people like transformational grammars, which relate sentences like that. The ideas don't help with the concepts like "complex sentence" that they teach in grade schools, just like calculus doesn't help with arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks John, that’s sort of what I was going for. Do you have any resources on this?

Comment: @meepyer It can only be a so-called 'simple' sentence. See my answer for why.

Comment: "Before the invention of the printing press" is a PP headed by the prep "before". And "before the printing press was invented" is not a clause but also a PP, again headed by the prep "before" with a content clause as complement.

Comment: @meepyer To learn what I'm talking about, you can try [my responses here](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler?tab=answers), or [McCawley's syntax book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English/k6-C5AWWqjQC?hl=en&gbpv=1).

Comment: Thanks John, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> *Before the invention of the printing press, books were very expensive.*

"Books were very expensive" is **not** an independent clause but just part of a clause, which in this case is the sentence as a whole.

"Before" is a preposition, thus "before the invention of the printing press" is a preposition phrase functioning as a temporal adjunct.

If you really must categorise the sentence as simple or complex, then it's a simple one since there is only one clause.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Sentence- Before the invention of the printing press, books were very expensive.

(A clause has a subject and a verb.)

Complex Sentence- Before the printing press was invented, books were very expensive.

Main/Principal Clause- Books were very expensive.

Subordinate/Dependent Clause- Before the printing press was invented.

Comment: I agree with the first part of what you say, but not the second. In the sentence _Before the printing press was invented, books were very expensive_ the matrix (main) clause is the whole sentence, and "books were very expensive" is just part of it. "Before" is a preposition and the expression "before the printing press was invented" is thus a preposition phrase functioning as a temporal adjunct.

Comment: 'Before the printing press was invented' is a clause, not a phrase.  A clause has a subject and a verb while a phrase does not have a subject and a verb.

Comment: No: it's a PP with the prep "before" as head with clause "the printing press was invented" functioning as its complement. Note that modern grammar regards "before" as a preposition, even when it has a clausal complement.

Comment: OK. Can we call it a clause?

Comment: Trad grammar treats "before" as a subordinator (or subordinating conjunction) and thus the whole expression as a clause with the verb "was" as head. But according to modern grammar, "before" is best treated as a preposition, functioning here as **head** of the phrase _before the printing press was invented_. It's thus a preposition phrase, not a clause, even though the head "before" has a clause (as opposed to a noun) as its complement.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Could you please tell me the sentence 'Before the printing press was invented, books were very expensive' is considered a complex one in modern English? Thank you so much for your contribution to my comment.

Comment: @BillJ I would like to know the sentence 'Before the printing press was invented, books were very expensive' is complex or simple (in modern English). Thank you so much for your valuable comments.

Comment: I would strongly recommend dropping the terms 'simple'. 'complex' and 'compound' when describing the basic clausal structure of sentences. Linguists and grammarians don't use those terms because they are not important, not even useful. The most important thing is to identify whether a sentence consists of a single clause or more than one, and to apply the terms 'matrix', 'main' and 'subordinate' to those clauses as appropriate.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much.